# Apache RewriteRule with dynamic directory

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a directory that changes with each new release and want to wildcard it for passthrough.

Directory example `/mysite/release-13/` Where the `-13` will increment to `-14`, etc. Would the following be the correct way to do this?

```
RewriteRule ^/mysite/release(.*) - [PT]
```

Comment: Not sure about the context, but `release(.*)` would be better as `release-\d+`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
release-\d+
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]